# Is it possible to develop an API for old software programs which don't have any API?

Tags: c#, api, dll, components, api-design

I am familiar with C# and want to communicate with an old software program (a word dictionary). Its developer never offered any API, to enable programmers to develop their programs in connection with this software program.

Now, I don't know is it possible to develop an API, a dll, for this software on my own? Is an especial knowledge needed? Is is crucial for developers to know what program language has been used for the original software? and finally how much is it possible in C#?

Comment: Are you able to access ANY information from the application? Any database that you can pull from? If not, accessing DLLs directly could put you in violation of the usage of the app. You'll need to read the terms of service and usage policies to see if it forbids reverse engineering the app. If so, you may want to stay away from doing anything.

Comment: Depends entirely on that old software in whether and in which ways you could interact with it. It might expose exported (callable) DLL functionality (difficult to figure out how to use them correctly), it might expose some COM or OLE functionality, but who knows... Another, perhaps more promising approach is to use some software like AutoHotkey or AutoIt to interact programmatically with its UI as well as getting data (text) back from UI elements. (This of course applies only to GUI programs, and not command line programs. For the latter, see the comment below from Magnetron)

Comment: This is a command line app? If so, you can try to write a wrapper that executes the old app with some parameters and parse the cmd output. But as @RyanC said, you have to look at the terms of service to see if you are allowed to do that

Comment: Actually the original software has been developed by java. Most of the files are binary. I need to use this dictionary as a helping tools in order to send its information according to the data of my program and send the word meaning to my program. indeed a sending and requesting process will be demanded.

Answer (score -3):

First, you have to figure out whats functionality you want to expose from that "old" software. Then create a C# REST api application that wraps the functionality of the software. Basically your REST api will work as a middleman in this case.

Comment: REST? Just for interfacing between some old software and a C# progam? I am trying to find a dictionary/thesaurus that lists under the phrase "old software" something like "_A synonym for web sevice. Also a tea plant._", but so far i couldn't find one...